# Python: unable to get value from the ini file

Tags: python, ini

I've a python use case where I'm:

- fetching data (read string) from an internal org portal.
- parse it using the split function to get relevant data (read digit, such as 101).
- passing that digit to a method to read a *.ini file with multiple sections. Each section's name are numbered, such as [101]
- Get the key, value from the *.ini file.

To achieve the same, below is the code I've:

```
class test():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.pbk=""
        self.pbkinfo=""

    def mkpbk(self):

        Info=othemodule.info('argument')
        summary=str(Info[1]['fields']['summary'])
        p=str(summary.split('-')[1])
        self.pbk=p

    def getPbkInfo(self): 
   
        for pb in pbkini.sections():
            if pb==self.pbk:
                self.pbkinfo={'action':pbkini.get(pb, "action")}
                return self.pbkinfo
```

summary="This is a summary 101"

Though **pbkini** has section [101] and key `action`, it returns the "None" value.

It works well when I replace `if pb==self.pbk` with `if pb=='101:` in **getPbkInfo()** method.

It again works if I manually put a string (say "this is a summary 101") against the summary variable in the **mkpbk()** method.

While debugging, I wished to see if the correct value of "self.pbk" is getting passed through all the stages, and it did.

So I fear that the method **getPbkInfo()** is searching for the variable name in the *.ini file section, instead of the variable value.

Can anyone help me get out of this situation?

Comment: In your example ```p=str(summary.split('-')[1])``` is splitting at a dash, but your string summary doesn't contain any. How should summary actually look like? Also, since your manually inserted string gives the correct output, I would guess that generating ```self.pbk``` results in the wrong string. Could it be that it contains any kind of whitespaces, maybe after using the split method?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Summary actually contains `-` string. However, you solved my query. There was whitespace. I could figure that out only by using `len(self.pbk)` method. Thank you. :)